# How to write JOLT Spec for nested arrays?

Tags: multidimensional-array, apache-nifi, specifications, jolt

I am trying to transform a JSON using JOLT. This JSON consists of nested arrays and I am unable to get the correct transformation.

This is the original JSON. Note that, there will always be a single "results" array with a single object. This object will always contain a single "rows" array. I want the fields from every element in the rows array.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "total_rows": 1390,
      "offset": 0,
      "rows": [
        {
          "id": "00407a53-5f45-11e9-8b9c-84cc507154b4",
          "key": "weather",
          "value": {
            "_id": "00407a53-5f45-11e9-8b9c-84cc507154b4",
            "_rev": "1-e996404ab9445c8ff753d45f61b5dc16",
            "deviceType": "home-iot",
            "deviceId": "12345",
            "eventType": "weather",
            "format": "json",
            "timestamp": "2019-04-15T06:09:17.311Z",
            "data": {
              "temperature": 44,
              "humidity": 75
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "00901ed4-5f44-11e9-94a1-84cc507154b4",
          "key": "weather",
          "value": {
            "_id": "00901ed4-5f44-11e9-94a1-84cc507154b4",
            "_rev": "1-519c4edaeb15ed2ca102d4aabe4a0339",
            "deviceType": "home-iot",
            "deviceId": "12345",
            "eventType": "weather",
            "format": "json",
            "timestamp": "2019-04-15T06:02:08.337Z",
            "data": {
              "temperature": -7,
              "humidity": 49
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the spec that I wrote:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "*": {
          "rows": {
            "*": {
              "value": {
                "deviceId": "[&4].deviceId",
                "deviceType": "[&4].deviceType",
                "eventType": "[&4].eventType",
                "timestamp": "[&4].timestamp",
                "data": {
                  "*": "[&5].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The expected JSON is:

```
[{
    "deviceId": "12345",
    "deviceType": "home-iot",
    "eventType": "weather",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-15T06:09:17.311Z",
    "temperature": 44,
    "humidity": 75
}, {
    "deviceId": "12345",
    "deviceType": "home-iot",
    "eventType": "weather",
    "timestamp": "2019-04-15T06:02:08.337Z",
    "temperature": -7,
    "humidity": 49
}]
```

However, my spec returns the following output:

```
[ {
  "deviceId" : [ "12345", "12345" ],
  "deviceType" : [ "home-iot", "home-iot" ],
  "eventType" : [ "weather", "weather" ],
  "timestamp" : [ "2019-04-15T06:09:17.311Z", "2019-04-15T06:02:08.337Z" ],
  "temperature" : [ 44, -7 ],
  "humidity" : [ 75, 49 ]
} ]
```

There is probably something wrong with the levels. But I am unable to figure it out. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2):

You're using the top-level array index with `&4` and `&5`, try `&2` and `&3` (the `rows` index) instead:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "results": {
        "*": {
          "rows": {
            "*": {
              "value": {
                "deviceId": "[&2].deviceId",
                "deviceType": "[&2].deviceType",
                "eventType": "[&2].eventType",
                "timestamp": "[&2].timestamp",
                "data": {
                  "*": "[&3].&"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: This is working. But I don't get how you identify which level to specify.

Comment: The index is 0-based, and you start at your current "level in the tree". So from `deviceId` (index 0) you go "back up the tree" to `value` (index 1), then up to the entry in the `rows` array (index 2).